# Vuex Store State won't update

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, store

I try to update my state:

```
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        user: {
            data: {},
            token: sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
        },
    },
```

with a mutation:

```
    mutations: {
        setUser: (state, userData) => {
            state.user.token = userData.token;
            state.user.data = userData.data.user;
            sessionStorage.setItem('TOKEN', userData.token);
        },
```

but nothing happens. the state won't be update. only the token works.

the api response is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": "agent 1",
        "extension": "adgsgdsdgh",
        "serverlist": [
            "server 1",
            "server 2"
        ],
        "countrylist": [
            "de",
            "en"
        ],
        "languagelist": [
            "DE",
            "FR"
        ]
    },
    "token": "3|wt80FMPmJVINt1ZgRwjk4N1RNdf2MI24bGRsujvF"
}
```

i try to show it like this:

```
    computed: {
        username() { return $store.state.user }
    },
    
.....

<template>
    <div class="setting">
        <p>User: </p><span>{{ username }}</span>
    </div>
```

i tried to change the mutations and the actions. also the component. but nothing changed it.

Comment: Hi! Where do you call a mutation "setUser"? And why a computed variable called "username" but, as I can see, it's a whole user object? Also, in a computed variable "username" it has to be "this.$store" not just "$store"

Comment: Hey. I call setUser from here
 login({ commit }, user) {
            return axiosClient.post('/login', user)
                .then(({data}) => {
                    commit('setUser', data);
                    return data;
                })
        },

Comment: the username computed was just a test if it would work like this. user is a whole object yes

Comment: Axios post method returns a response object - https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema You have to provide to the commit function "data.data" not just "data", because "data" in your case it's a whole response object.

Comment: i tried that before. if i do data.data inside the action then the token won't be set. if i pass only data and inside set user userData.token i can set the token but not the user object. this is only data {data: {…}, token: '3|wt80FMPmJVINt1ZgRwjk4N1RNdf2MI24bGRsujvF'}

Comment: {user: 'agent 1', extension: 'adgsgdsdgh', serverlist: Array(2), countrylist: Array(2), languagelist: Array(2)} this is data.data. but the token is missing. also i cant set the user

Comment: The explanation that it doesn't work properly is not constructive. It's unknown how exactly you determine that it doesn't work. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: if i console log this.state.user inside the action after the mutation i get this Proxy(Object) {data: {…}, token: '3|wt80FMPmJVINt1ZgRwjk4N1RNdf2MI24bGRsujvF'} so it should have worked. but i can't see any change in frontend

Comment: @EstusFlask the value of the state.user does not change after the mutation.

Comment: But it's $store.state.user.data, not $store.state.user.data, because this is the actual data that is expected to be consumed. You shouldn't rely on a way an object is stringified to debug it. I don't see other problems. if this is not the case, please, provide a way to reproduce.